# Flex 4- warning: -3608:

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have copied code from Adobe Tour de Flex(Other components=>containers=>TitledBorderBox)

```
var style:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("TitledBorderBox");
```

but I'm getting a warning in TitledBorderBox.as:

`warning: -3608: 'getStyleDeclaration' has been deprecated since 4.0. Please use 'IStyleManager2.getStyleDeclaration on a style manager instance'.`

how to remove this warning? please help me.

Comment: Use 'IStyleManager2.getStyleDeclaration on a style manager instance?

Comment: :) me too thought the same but dint work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration('TitledBorderBox')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
var style:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("TitledBorderBox");
```

Since Flex 4 every `UIComponent` instance [has corresponding field](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#styleManager).

Or you can switch your project to use Flex 3 SDK.

Comment: thank you for answer but i have to use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager otherwise i will get error undefined property:styleManager

Comment: I recommend you not to use misc static fields and globals. Just switch your project to use Flex SDK >= 4.1.